# "mvn allure:serve" generates report to an temp folder

Tags: allure

I was going through the io.qameta.allure documentation and saw this option to generate allure report using "mvn allure:serve"

mvn allure:serve

The report will be generated into a temp folder. The web server with results will start. You can additionally configure the server timeout

regarding the below lines, can we modify in the configuration to generate reports under the particulate folder instead of the temp folder?

do anyone have information about it using this command only?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by defining a configuration > reportDirectory for allure-maven in your pom.xml file.
Example: in a java/selenium/testng project, here is the reporting section of pom.xml file:

```
<reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>${allure.version}</reportVersion>
                    <reportDirectory>allure-report/</reportDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. if you are firing command mvn allure:serve it'll generate in temp folder only

Comment: You are right, it might be because I'm not using serve but two commands I forgot to mention:
`allure generate ./allure-results --clean`
`allure open ./allure-report/`
Maybe you can try these?

Answer (score 1):

In order to generate allure reports you need to use: `mvn allure:report`.

To specify the path of the report generated use the allure [maven plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-maven/2.11.2) and in the pom.xml file use this:

```
<configuration>
            <reportVersion>2.14.0</reportVersion>
            <resultsDirectory>*allure result path*</resultsDirectory>
            <reportDirectory>*allure report path*</reportDirectory>
</configuration>
```

The following command: `mvn allure:serve` always uses a temp folder on your device and I haven't seen anywhere in their documentation the ability of defining the path when using the `serve` command.